# How do I write and read files on one program?

Tags: c

I'd like to write two multiplication tables in a txt file on one program, read the written file, and print it out on the screen.
C2374 error occurs in my code.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //File Write
    FILE* fp = fopen("99.txt", "wt");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        puts("file open fail.");
        return 1;
    }
    int i = 2;
    int j;
    for (j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
        {
      fprintf(fp, "\t  %d X %d = %2d \n", i, j, i * j);
        }
    
    //File Read
    char str[100];
    FILE* fp = fopen("99.txt", "rt");

    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp) != NULL)
        printf(str);
   
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
    
}
```

How can I get the 'desired output'?
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb6L5.png)

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Close the file before the 2nd `fopen()` or research `freopen()`.

Comment: You have defined two variables with the same name `fp`, which is not allowed in C.

Comment: Post desired output as text here instead of an external image.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare `FILE *fp` twice.  Minimized scope of variables.  Changed loop condition from `j <= 9` to `j < 10` which how it's usually done.  Use `freopen()` to change the mode of the file handle:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* fp = fopen("99.txt", "wt");
    if(!fp) {
        puts("file open fail.");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 2, j = 1; j < 10; j++)
        fprintf(fp, "\t  %d X %d = %2d \n", i, j, i * j);

    fp = freopen(NULL, "r", fp);
    if(!fp) {
        puts("file reopen fail.");
        return 1;
    }
    char str[100];
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp) != NULL)
        printf(str);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

and expected output:

```
          2 X 1 =  2 
          2 X 2 =  4 
          2 X 3 =  6 
          2 X 4 =  8 
          2 X 5 = 10 
          2 X 6 = 12 
          2 X 7 = 14 
          2 X 8 = 16 
          2 X 9 = 18
```